# Can "strong" be used as a noun?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I see the word "strong" refers to a group of army in two contexts:

- In [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/OutOfTheLoop/comments/77cda0/what_is_a_loop_a_primer_on_increasing_the/?st=jrjd4a2u&sh=e9885a96):

  > We're now a sub of nearly six hundred thousand **strong**

  In this context the word "strong" refers to the subscribers of the subreddit.
- In [this game](https://youtu.be/p6MdBOQHnDs?t=2315):

  > Here we go loading up for a huge **strong**

  Here the word refers to a group of army about to be dropped to the opponent's base.

But [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/strong) doesn't count this as a meaning of the word. Is this the case the dictionary hasn't caught up the usage of the word? Can it be used as a noun?

Comment: You seem to have overlooked something in your Oxford dictionaries link, namely sense four: "Used after a number to indicate the size of a group.
‘a hostile crowd several thousands strong’"

Comment: At a point prior to the word in question, they are talking about fighting off brute force attacks. In fact, if you go to 38:18 (and look at the closed captioning), what's said is "*comes down to fantastic sized* ***storms*** *he might...*" It makes more sense that they are *continuing* to talk about **storms** but that the word is simply garbled.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In your first example, "strong" is an adjective. The writer is not saying that the "sub" is made up of 600,000 "strongs". He's saying that it is strong. How strong? 600,000 strong. It's like saying "Bob is six feet tall" or "The river is 20 miles long." He is attaching a number to an adjective.

I have no idea what the writer in the second example is trying to say. Perhaps he didn't finish the sentence; he meant "loading up for a huge strong ATTACK" or some such. As given, the quote is not grammatically correct and doesn't make sense.

I don't recall ever reading or hearing "strong" used as a noun in a coherent sentence.

Comment: Strong can be a **nominalized adjective** that is used **as though** it is a noun.  Example: _"We accept the rich and the poor.  We accept the weak and the strong."_  It truly is an adjective, but works like a noun.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalized_adjective

Comment: @Keeta - You can tell it's still an adjective because it can be modified with adverbs: "We accept the **unfortunately weak** and the **exceptionally strong**," or take adjectival suffixes like superlatives: "We accept the **weakest** and the **strongest**." Both of these are forbidden for nouns.

Comment: @Keeta Thank you, I thought of a very similar example but didn't know the terminology to describe it! Interesting to note that some adjectives have been nominalized so thoroughly that they have been converted to nouns.

Comment: @Keeta: The nominalized adjective requires a determiner.  ***The** quick and **the** dead*.

Comment: "of 600,000 strong" is incorrect, however.  It should be "we are a sub of 600,000," full stop, or else "the sub is 600,000 strong."  This incorrect "of 600,000 strong" is becoming more common because the idiom itself is somewhat uncommon.

Comment: 'Strong' can be used as a noun: the strong of a sword, more commonly known by the French term 'forte', is the one third of the blade that's closest to the hilt. That's a very specialised use, however.

Comment: @Galastel I am not familiar with that usage and couldn't find it in a conventional dictionary. If it's a technical term, though, okay, fair enough.

Comment: @keeta Okay, adjectives can sort of be used as nouns, though I would say this is not really changing the part of speech but elision: we are omitting the noun. Like if I say, "There are two kinds of people in the world: the diligent and the lazy", am I really using "diligent" and "lazy" as nouns? I'd say I am using them as adjectives and omitting the noun "people" as obvious in context.

Comment: It is a technical term. https://www.swordsknivesanddaggers.com/anatomy-of-a-sword.html

Comment: This thread is a bit baffling. Not only *can* strong be a noun. It's not even all that uncommon. It's like "brave". "The few, the strong, the brave". Referring to "those who are strong", or "those who are brave".

Answer (score 10):

Although "strong" may look like a noun in "... a hundred thousand *strong*", it still acts as an adjective phrase modifying "sub".  This idiomatic expression is much the same as any other adjective such as "many" or "large":

> The khan's army was **large**
>
> The khan's army was **a hundred thousand strong**.

"Strong" does sound like a noun in the second sentence, but if so is probably jargon specific to players of Starcraft.  That being said, it's possible the commentator misspoke and meant to say ["throng"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/throng), or that it's a slang abbreviation for "a *strong* counterattack".

Or (as choster mentions) it could be "drop" -- the video is edited at that point so the word is garbled.  That sounds more reasonable for the context.

Otherwise I can think of no common use of "strong" as a noun, although of course you can always make up your own if it fits the context.

Comment: I can confirm that it is not a jargon in StarCraft at all

Comment: @Ooker: "jargon" is uncountable.

Comment: The word the commentator uses is unintelligible. *tromp* ?

Comment: @Mazura From my StarCraft experience, I would venture *drop*.

Comment: @choster  it could be "drop".  The video is edited at that point so it's garbled.

Comment: Can confirm that though it's uncommon, it's not specific to video games. I love using it this way, it seems so poetic!

Comment: @Andrew it is not edited. The screen just switches to a different location

Comment: I do think there is a relatively common way of using "strong" as a noun, though it doesn't apply to the phrases here. In phrases like "the strong eat the weak" or "only the strong survive" it is a nominalized adjective, which is an adjective turned into a noun.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not able to comment, so I'm putting this in an answer.

In your second source, the caster actually says "loading up for a huge DROP". A drop being a piece of jargon referring to the fact that these units will shortly be dropped into the opponent's base. I can see how if you are primed to hear strong, you might hear strong instead.

Comment: Agreed. In addition, the other commentator cuts off the end of the word, making it sound like "...loading up for a huge DRAH **/** Yeah, this is nice..." Both commentators repeat the words "drop" or "drops" multiple times a couple sentences later.

Comment: Listening carefully, it is clear that the caster starts the word with /s/, a fricative unvoiced sound, not /d/, a plosive voiced one. In the transcript it is also identified as "strong"

Comment: @Ooker who wrote the transcript? If this is from YouTube, take it from me that their subtitles are not infallible. I see plenty of mistakes especially if the audio is of a somewhat poor/inferior quality

Comment: Drop makes sense with what the image shows. It's just pronounced badly/exaggeratedly.

Comment: @Mari-LouA what do you think about the /s/ sound?

Comment: Note that the YouTube subs say at one point [*some circus would have just lost 2/3*](https://youtu.be/p6MdBOQHnDs?t=1823) instead of "sorts of" In the snippet you posted it is difficult to understand, I hear "a huuuuuge (?) tron" which again makes no sense.

Comment: @Ooker, i think what you hear as an s is just the g which is lengthened to show excitement.

Comment: @Ooker As stated previously, both commentators go on to *clearly* use the word "drop" multiple times in the following 30 seconds or so. Given that "strong" makes **no** sense here but "drop" does, it's difficult to justify your hard-line position on this.

Comment: @Ooker FWIW I just listened to it again on a different system - cheap tablet speakers instead of headphones - and I do get a hint of an /s/ there but as Carsten says, it's early enough that it's more properly a slurred g (almost an /sh/) in "huge"

Comment: @GalacticCowboy it seems that it is actually "huge drop". The "huge" is stressed so /g/ combines with /d/ to become an /s/. Meanwhile, "drop" is spoken fleetingly, so maybe the /p/ sound is swallowed.

Comment: @Mari-LouA well the correct sentence is "some Zergs would just have lost...". I'm not sure where to put "sort of" in there. Anyway, what do you think if it's actually "huge drop", where the /p/ is swallowed?

Comment: @Ooker my not knowing the game meant I clutched at the nearest equivalent word that made more sense than "circus". But you're right Zergs is the term used. My main point being is that YouTube subtitles are often imprecise or plain wacky because the voice recognition tool employed will not try to make sense of what is being said unlike a human being. As for the P sound, I have no idea but "strong" does not make sense in that sentence unless it is argot/slang.

Answer (score 6):

In the first example, "of six hundred thousand strong" is *incorrect.* It should be

> We're now a sub of nearly six hundred thousand.

It could also be

> We're now a sub that is nearly six hundred thousand strong

The construction "of 600,000 strong" is becoming more common because the idiom itself is somewhat uncommon, but it is not the traditional form of this expression.

I also note that you seem to have overlooked something in your Oxford dictionaries link, namely sense four:

> Used after a number to indicate the size of a group.
>
> *‘a hostile crowd several thousands strong’*

Comment: You're right, I was just looking for the noun section of the word, and not really for it carefully.

Answer (score 4):

Just as in "ten foot *tall*" the word **tall** means "in height", and in the phrase "six feet *deep*" the word **deep** means "in depth", in the phrase "an army ten-thousand *strong*" the word **strong** means "in strength".

**Strong** is misused in your second example.

Comment: should it be "ten-thousand people strong"? Btw, why do we have "ten **foot** tall" but "six **feet** deep"?

Comment: It can also be "six foot deep".

Comment: No, it "should" not be "ten thousand people strong" but it *could* be.

Comment: @Ooker "We" are obviously "people" so there is no need to say something obvious by repeating the word in "10,000 *people* strong".

Comment: I think there is a difference in usage between between "foot" and "feet" at least in British English. In a phrase linked to what it described by the verb "to be,"  feet is more common than foot - i.e. "The wall was ten feet tall" not "ten foot tall". But if the phrase is acting like an adjective preceding a noun, foot sounds right and feet sounds wrong - "The garden was surrounded by a ten foot [high] wall" not "a ten feet wall". The reason might be that "The garden" is singular, but "feet" is plural and therefore sets the reader off in the wrong direction to understand the whole sentence.

Comment: @alephzero that describes the literary standard in the US as well, but in dialect and colloquial contexts, including in some dialects of England, it's common to hear units of measure in the singular even when the value is an integer greater than 1.

Comment: @alephzero As an American, I can say that I've heard "a ten foot wall" very often and would consider it correct.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes.**

It is common for the two halves of the length of a sword's blade to be described as the 'forte' and the 'foible', or the 'strong' and the 'weak'.  When parrying, the strong of your own blade should be used against the opponent's weak.

Fencers of all stripes will as happily refer to a sword's 'forte' or 'strong' as an actual thing as they would it's grip or guard.  (Grip and guard, interestingly, being both nouns and verbs.)

Use of the English or not depends on whether the individual prefers their turn of phrase at that moment to be functional or flowery.  But, yes - if grip, guard, or pommel can be a noun then so can strong.

Answer (score 2):

In the second example, it seems that it is actually "huge drop". The "huge" is stressed so /g/ combines with /d/ to become an /s/. Meanwhile, "drop" is spoken fleetingly, so maybe the /p/ sound is swallowed.

Just my guess.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, it can be used as a noun, but not in the examples you give.**

In instances like "the strong eat the weak" or "only the strong survive" it is a [nominalized adjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalized_adjective). As wikipedia notes, this is "an adjective that has undergone nominalization, and is thus used as a noun." Nominalized adjectives are commonly used to indicate a specific group of people, such as the rich, the poor, the weak, or the strong.

The entry for [nominalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalization) explains a bit about the process and includes more examples if you'd like further reading.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like everyone kind of beat this to the ground.

If you can put 'the' in front of a word, it is a NOUN.

If you can say that he/she/it is ___. Then it is an ADJECTIVE.

Comment: "The bold and the beautiful" Are they nouns or adjectives or both? *Have you ever watched the "The bold and the beautiful"?* Is "The" a noun then?

Comment: In this case, Bold and Beautiful are used as nouns.

'The' is an article, not a noun.

Comment: I'm just saying to be careful about stating things as absolute truths. Add "normally" and no one will mutter a word.